# Understanding dart map, not getting expected value for given key

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a debug print line:

```
String id = tileMap['id'] as String;
_tiles[id] = td;

String t = 'blank';
print('${_tiles} ${_tiles[id]} ${_tiles[t]} ${_tiles['blank']} $id ${_tiles.containsKey('blank')} ${id == t} ${id == 'blank'}');
```

The `tileMap` variable is a Map from jsonDecode.

and its giving me:

```
flutter: {blank: Instance of 'TileData'} Instance of 'TileData' null null blank false true true
```

I don't understand why it only works when using the original `id` String variable, but not the `t` String variable or a String literal. The last 2 `true` outputs tell be `id`, `t`, and `'blank'` are all equal, but the map only returns the content for the `id` variable?

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: That does look very strange yeah. I would imagine that this behavior could only happen if the entry got removed somehow after the first readout. What if you do `print('${_tiles} ${_tiles[id]} ${_tiles[t]} ${_tiles}');`? Is the last print still the same map? Or switch the order and do `print('${_tiles} ${_tiles[t]} ${_tiles[id]} ${_tiles}');`? Same print then?

Comment: What kind of `Map` object does `_tiles` refer to?  How was that `Map` object constructed?  This sounds like it's maybe a `LinkedHashMap` with `equals` and `hashCode` callbacks that aren't consistent.

Comment: @ivo - flutter: {blank: Instance of 'TileData'} Instance of 'TileData' null {blank: Instance of 'TileData'}

It looks the same to me.

Comment: @jamesdlin - This was it.